# "margin" - pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I've just been corrected by one of my friends when I pronounced "margin" as  /ˈmɑːɡɪn/. Indeed, I looked it up and dictionaries only give /ˈmɑːdʒɪn/. Does anybody really pronounce it the way I did it? I can't explain why it felt so natural to use /ɡ/ instead of /dʒ/?

[dictionary.cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/margin)
[www.collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/margin)

Comment: Hello, shogun. To avoid contributers needlessly repeating your research, please put down the dictionaries only giving the pronunciation /ˈmɑːdʒɪn/ (which is the only way I've ever heard the word pronounced).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Do you mean to drop them or to denote them in his question?  It took me a couple of read-throughs of your comment to parse it.

Comment: ELU 'I looked it up and dictionaries only give /ˈmɑːdʒɪn/.' _Which_ dictionaries?

Comment: Did you try using the "listen" feature of modern online dictionaries?  Also there are recorded clips available on youtube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, nobody does. What's more, being derived from Latin, it being pronounced that way would require it be spelled "marguin."  In words derived from Latin, a G immediately before an I is always a soft G, never a hard G.

> "Speaking Church Latin - Soften consonants before ae, e, oe, and i."
>   (click this [link](https://www.wikihow.com/Pronounce-Latin#targetText=In%20Church%20Latin%2C%20the%20%22g,j%22%20in%20%22jet.%22) and see part 4, bullet 1)

Comment: The pronunciation of church Latin has always varied over time and between different local traditions. Monographs have been written on the subject. The Wikihow reference does not do justice to this very complicated subject.

Comment: Well, maybe it does, but in presenting the subject as one susceptible to rules it oversimplifies so much that I doubt its trustworthiness even on simple points. But I am sure we both agree that how the word might once have been pronounced by Latin speakers is quite tangential to how it is generally pronounced today by native speakers. On that  it is clear that the 'g' is soft.

Comment: "In words derived from Latin, a G immediately before an I is always a soft G, never a hard G." There's at least one counterexample, *gibbous.*

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/margin) pronounces it `\ˈmär-jən\`.  And their pronunciator pronounces it the way I generally hear it and speak it.  The "r" sound should be audible (except in Boston).

Basically, the "mar" is the same as in "marshal", and the "gin" is the same as the alcohol.

Comment: Aren't there any British English versions similar to the Boston version?